# Topology Edit Tool in ArcGIS Engine

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, topology

Is a Topology Edit Tool available "out of the box" for ArcGIS Engine 10? Or do I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your topology is stored in a database, [this sample](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/esriGeodatabase/ITopologyGraph__ReshapeEdgeGeometry.htm) seems like it could be changed to [open a topology from the geodb](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenTopology_Method/0025000009v9000000/) (instead of getting it from the topo extension).

[IWorkspaceEdit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IWorkspaceEdit2_Interface/002500000m5w000000/) is available with ArcEngine, though you might need the [geodatabase update extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisengine/extensions.html) for engine.

Comment: That's the problem (_my_ problem, that is) with assuming that a sample available in a prior release will be included in the 10.0 documentation. Thanks for pointing this out. (Of course, I'll still have to write it myself, but this is better than nothing.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you find this topic:

[EditorExt](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/0021000000w3000000/)

There's a Topology Extension section with links to several classes, etc. Although on further thought, I think you're correct that there may not be an out-of-the-box topology edit tool in ArcEngine.

Comment: Yes, EditorExt and, more specifically, the TopologyExtension appear able to handle topological editing. I was hoping that I could simply add a tool to the toolbar (i.e. that the code to perform topology editing was pre-written), but that appears not to be the case.

Comment: Actually, it looks like [EditorExt](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/0021000000w3000000/) and [TopologyExtension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0021000000vq000000) are _only_ available for ArcGIS Desktop. I need to write _everything_ related to topology from scratch in Engine.